# Should I postfix application.yml?

Tags: java, spring, maven

My project structure (Spring / maven):

```
src / main / resources / application.yml
src / test / resources / application.yml
```

This is working well (when I launch test, it takes the test application.yml).

But often, I see posts where the application.yml is postfix to take the active profile:
i.e.: application-test.yml for test profile.

What is the best practice here ? What is the point of postfixing the name ? When is it useful exactly ?

Comment: Just a thought: What you're doing works.  The day that it doesn't work, reconsider the other way.  Until then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, the application needs to find the configuration file. There are two approaches:

- The app knows in which context it is run and finds the correct config file for that context. Usually this just means “look for a specific name in the current working directory”.
- You explicitly provide a config file to the app.

With the first approach – the app searches for a config file with a specific name – there can be only one config file per directory. This has a number of potential problems:

- If you want a different config you need to change the relevant context, e.g. launch from a different working directory.
- A user doesn't necessarily realize which config file is being used. This can e.g. cause a reliance on bad defaults.
- If a developer needs to make local tweaks to the config, they must edit a file with a specific name. This file will be marked as dirty by the version control system, yet such local tweaks should never be committed.

For these reasons, I believe that providing config explicitly is better. The disadvantage there is that a config file *must* be provided in order for the app to run, which makes setup a tiny bit more difficult.

So if we have multiple configuration files, how do we tell which is which? A naming schema like `application-$CONTEXT.yml` looks perfectly sensible. If I need to make local tweaks I just copy the config to a new filename and do my changes there.

Note that strictly speaking, the file system doesn't care whether you store the config file as `project/$CONTEXT/application.yml` or `project/application-$CONTEXT.yml`. There is only a real difference if the default config file is e.g. chosen by the appplication's current working directory.